# GAE Socket API error - ApplicationError: 4 Unknown error

Tags: sockets, google-app-engine

We have an app engine cron that checks the liveness of a number of DNS servers using dnspython.  It has been working without issue until [12/Nov/2014:13:28:12 -0800] (about 12 hours ago) where it started failing 100% of the time with the following:

```
DNS Lookup failed: 'ApplicationError: 4 Unknown error.'.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../handlers/tasks.py", line 150, in _checkDNSServer
    answers = resolver.query(domain, 'A', source='')
  File "lib/dns/resolver.py", line 830, in query
    source_port=source_port)
  File "lib/dns/query.py", line 213, in udp
    s.bind(source)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 222, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 660, in bind
    self._CreateSocket(bind_address=address)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 611, in _CreateSocket
    raise _SystemExceptionFromAppError(e)
ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 4 Unknown error.
```

The code in question is fairly simple ...

```
def _checkDNSServer(self, ip):
    """ Return true if the server is up and responds within 1 second.
        False the server is down or responded slowly
    """
    domain = 'www.testdomain.com'
    resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
    resolver.nameservers = [ip]

    starttime = datetime.now()
    try:
        answers = resolver.query(domain, 'A', source='')
        duration = datetime.now() - starttime

        logging.debug("DNS Lookup Time %s" % duration)
        # Max delay of 1 second
        if duration > timedelta(seconds=1):
            return False

        return True
    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        logging.error("DNS Lookup failed: '%s'.  %s", e, tb)
        return False
```

- the code continues to work on the local development server
- billing is enabled
- quota is sufficient
- no changes to app engine release version (1.9.16) before/after the error appearing
- target servers are live and responding ok

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was a transient issue and is now resolved.

Comment: This is an answer.  Maybe not the only answer.